# adding and removing image on html canvas is too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, html5-canvas

```
$("#video-section").mouseout(function(){
        canvas.remove(boxImage);
});
$("#video-section").mouseover(function(){
    canvas.add(boxImage);
});
```

That is the code for changing/hiding image of mouse control.

But as you guessed that is super slow and delayed.

What might be the best way so that there will be no lagging of showing / hiding the image.

Tried hide and show but not working, may be it is because of canvas context. New to canvases and struggling with this from so long time.

Comment: You can cache the image by using image object. Changing image src everytime might be slow if image is big.

Comment: can its possible for you to create a working snippet or fiddle for this?

Comment: @vijayP Unfortunately no :(

Comment: Ok. What you mean by mouse control. Do you want to say mouse pointer or mouse arrow? And you don't want to show that mouse pointer once it's on your canvas area?

Comment: Take multiple layers of canvas overlapping each other and show and hide the canvas as per your requirement would help you to improve the performance.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve -- your question only hints at revealing some kind of image when your mouse is over #video-selection?

Manipulating the DOM is slow.

Instead...

Create a canvas element covering your #video-selection for faster drawing of `boxImage`:

- Create a #canvas element.
- Wrap both the #video-selection & #canvas in a div #wrapper.
- Use CSS to cover #video-selection with #canvas.

  ```
  <div id=wrapper width=320 height=240>
      <div id='video-selection' width=320 height=240></div>
      <canvas id=canvas width=320 height=240></canvas>
  </div>

  #wrapper{position:relative;}
  #video-selection, #canvas{position:absolute;}
  ```

Then listen for mouseover / mouseout events to display `boxImage` on the covering canvas:

```
// canvas related vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// set where boxImage will be drawn on the canvas
var boxX=20;
var boxY=30;

// on mouseout, clear boxImage off the canvas
$("#video-section").mouseout(function(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
});

// on mouseover, draw boxImage on the canvas
$("#video-section").mouseover(function(){
    context.drawImage(boxImage,boxX,boxY);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/docs/addLayers/

> Hiding layers
>
> To temporarily hide a layer, set its visible property to false. *This also will prevent any of the layer's events from triggering*.
>
> To show the layer again, set its visible property to true.
>
> Test
>   
>   `// This layer should be invisible
>   $('canvas').drawRect({
>     layer: true,
>     visible: false, // ** false hides and no events. true shows. **
>     fillStyle: '#585',
>     x: 100, y: 100,
>     width: 100, height: 50
>   });`

This technique indicates the need for 2 layers for a mouseover/out effect since visibility=false "will prevent any of the layer's events from triggering".

So maybe your boxImage layer and another transparent single pixel layer.

If that's still too slow you'll have to go for a css visibility solution that operates on the containers and not the canvas drawings.